# Problems with legend tag when I am unhiding and re-hiding it in a fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

So I am trying to do this thing where a `legend` tag shows when the input box is being clicked. The idea is there is that the `input` box is inside a `fieldset` and the legend as a  `hidden` class first. If the input box is on focus or clicked, the `hidden` class will be removed and it will show like this

[image]

I also added a part wherein if was left blank the `legend` tag will disappear by re-adding the removed
`hidden` class. However, it also leaves awkward whitespace in a place where it is formerly was like this
[image]

Did I do something wrong? Is there something I must do first?
The code is here:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    var div = $(this).closest('.wrapper');
    var next = $(this).closest('.wrapper').next();
    div.addClass('hidden');
    next.removeClass('hidden');
  })
})



$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    $('input').each(function(index) {
      const legend = $(this).closest('fieldset').children('legend');
      if (($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == " ") && $(this).is(":focus") == false) {
        if (legend.hasClass('hidden') == false) {
          legend.addClass('hidden');
          $(this).css("margin-top", "10px");
        }
      } else {
        legend.removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).css("margin-top", "-150%");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap');
html {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #EDE9E8;
}

.cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

form {
  /*border: 3px solid red;/**/
  width: 57%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  background: white;
  width: 95%;
  height: 65%;
  padding: 3%;
  margin-top: 8%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.border_none {
  border: none;
}

.border_black {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.with_image {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.with_image img {
  width: 40%;
}

.input_box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 70%;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.wrapper label {
  font-size: 150%;
}

legend {
  font-size: 12px;
  /*border: 2px solid black;/**/
}

.wrapper fieldset input[type="text"],
.wrapper fieldset input[type="email"],
.wrapper input[type="password"],
input[type="number"] {
  width: 100 %;
  height: 100 %;
  margin - top: 10 px;
  border: none;
  /**/
}

.wrapper fieldset input[type="text"]: focus,
.wrapper input[type="email"]: focus,
.wrapper input[type="password"]: focus,
input[type="number"]: focus {
  outline: none;
}

.child fieldset {
  overflow: hidden;
  border - radius: 20 px;
}

.wrapper select {
  margin - left: 14 %;
  height: 40 px;
}

.wrapper.next {
  background: #2c54db;
  width: 15%;
  height: 8%;
  border: white;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset class="wrapper border_none">
      <div class="child">
        <h1>Identity</h1>
        <fieldset class="input_box" class="input_outer">
          <legend class="input_tag hidden">First Name</legend>
          <input class="input_inner" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        </fieldset><br>
        <fieldset class="input_box" class="input_outer">
          <legend class="input_tag hidden">Last Name</legend>
          <input class="input_inner" type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </fieldset><br>
        <label>Civil Status</label>
        <select name="civil_status" id="cv_stat">
          <option value="Single">Single</option>
          <option value="Married">Married</option>
          <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
          <option value="Annulled">Anulled</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <fieldset class="input_box" class="input_outer">
          <legend class="input_tag hidden">Email</legend><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </fieldset>
        <button type="button" class="next">
                            Next
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="child with_image">
        <img src="../images/registration/user_folder_125px.png">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="wrapper hidden">
      <div class="child">
        <h1>Password</h1>
        <fieldset class="input_box" class="input_outer">
          <legend class="input_tag hidden">Password</legend>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <fieldset class="input_box" class="input_outer">
          <legend class="input_tag hidden">Confirm Password</legend>
          <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </fieldset>
        <button type="button" class="next">
                            Next
                        </button>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="child">

  </fieldset>

  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your markup is invalid at `</div><div class="child"></fieldset>`, check your opening/closing tags

Comment: Oh thank you I just realized that, however fixing it only solved a different problem tho :(

Comment: I could reproduce what you describe (chunk of the border missing after "First name" label disappears), but I have no idea why this is happening. Toggling the `<input class="input_inner">` with `display:none` and `display:initial` makes the chunk come back and the border plain again, but really I don't know why. Feels like some CSS bug or something

Comment: Exactly! At first, I thought it was because I set the margin-top of the `inner input box` too much so I resorted in readjusting it, however, the problem persisted so I had to ask why the problem is happening

Comment: Anyways, thank you for the fix @JeremyThille it really `display:initial` fixed the bug tho it is still bugging me